# Withdraw from job before starting

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, contractors

I am in the UK and am about to start a short term contract that I would like to back out off. My employment contract is for two months, I have no probation period and there is no notice period explicitly mentioned in my contract.

Is the proper thing to do to send in a letter of resignation before I start? Or will I have to start, and serve out a statutory one week notice?

I understand this will burn bridges, but am trying to do the right thing and minimise disruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commonly before you even start with a company, a fair amount of work has to be done to prepare for your arrival, even if it's only for a short time. Your computer needs to be set up, you need an email account set up, be put on payroll, your superiors would set aside time from their day to introduce you to people, etc.

With this in mind, it would be courteous to inform your soon-to-be employer as soon as possible. Waiting until the day you start is not likely to go down well. This means they have to do less work for no reason and reduces the amount of bridge-burning involved.

Given the short contract and if you have a contracted one-week notice period, it may be worthwhile *offering* to work the one week if it is to the company's benefit, but it is unlikely they will take up this offer. They may say it's not worthwhile and arrange to mutually sever the contract. Explain to them why you have to end things before they begin and at least offer to work the week-long notice period (if there is one). In short, explain to them as soon as possible that you would like to withdraw from your arranged work and hear them out on what to do next.

Comment: This is good, I will do this.

Comment: I would open with "It's not you, it's me"...